# Efficient "Insert" function in linked list

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list

In an interview I was asked to write an insert function for linked list in such a way that after the insertion, the element towards the head side of the inserted element should be greater and the tail side should be smaller when compared to inserted element.

I had implemented the following steps in my code:

1. initially sort the linked list in descending order.
2. get the element.
3. insert the element in such way that the linked list will be in descending order even after insertion.

But I was told that my way was not efficient.

Please let me know if there are efficient way to achieve the same.

Comment: I *think* they wanted you to assume the link is already sorted originally, and your insert should maintain this sort. (I would ask in the interview if it is indeed the intent). In this case, no sort is needed - just iterate until you find the place of insertion and insert it.

Comment: @amit: No, the linked is not sorted at the beginning.

Comment: To me, @amit's interpretation is the only one that makes sense. I would also asked the interviewer for clarification.

Comment: OK, so the list is not sorted and you're not allowed to sort it. Are you allowed/expected to make any changes to that list (e.g. permute elements) other than inserting the new element?

Comment: [partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)? `list.insert(partition(list.begin(),list.end(),element_greater_than(value)),value)`.

Comment: @llonesmiz: Now that you mention it, that's another possible interpretation. I have to say that I find the question to be very ambiguously worded.

Comment: Possibly, your sorting algorithm was bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort is an `O(n log n)` operation. If you read the question carefully they never say the list should be sorted, so don't do the sort operation. What you should do instead is start with a new list with only your element, then for each element of the original list append it either to the front (if greater than the new element) or otherwise at the back.